# Julia - formatted string interpolation in command

Tags: command, julia

I'd like to run a shell command in Julia with command object. However, when constructing a command, I'd need to construct the args in a string first with some logic, then construct a command out of those args.

The issue I have is, when the string has spaces, the command object automatically put quoted it. Below is the example.

```
julia> my_str = "--arg1 test --arg2 test --flag1"
"--arg1 test --arg2 test --flag1"

julia> app_name = "test.jl"
"test.jl"

julia> `julia $app_name $my_str`
`julia test.jl '--arg1 test --arg2 test --flag1'`
```

Is there any workaround for this?

In case this info is needed, I'm in `Julia 1.1.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a list seems to work instead of constructing a string of arguments. This behavior is explained in [this](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/running-external-programs/#command-interpolation-1) section of Julia docs.

```
julia> `julia $app_name $(split(my_str))`
`julia test.jl --arg1 test --arg2 test --flag1`
```

Comment: Just split up your string into an array of words by splitting on space character.

Comment: @StevenSiew That's exactly what I did. This is the answer, by the way, so it's already working.